# How can I describe a character in a configuration file, based on its ASCII value?

Tags: c#, configuration, character

While programming in C#, single characters can be used, based on their ASCII value, something like:

```
if (whatever_string.EndsWith("\u06"))
...
```

I would like to put the ASCII string in the configuration. As regularly I need string manipulation to be done, I would like to add it in the configuration as a string, so my object looks as follows:

```
Object definition
...
  public string AckChars { get; private set; }
```

And in the app.config file, I've put it as follows:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="AckChars" value="\u06"/>
```

But, when I read this from the configuration, based on this:

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
...
string value;
value = appSettings[key];
```

My `AckVars` looks as follows in the watch-window (don't laugh :-) ):

```
AckChars[0] 92 '\\' char
AckChars[1] 117 'u' char
AchChars[2] 48 '0'  char
AckChars[3] 54 '6'  char
```

So, what's the way to enter a character in a C# configuration file, knowing that it will be read as an entire string?

**Edit after answer from [Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880990/olivier-jacot-descombes)**

After having put `U+0006` in the configuration file, this is the result:

```
AckChars[0]  85 'U'  char
AckChars[1]  43 '+'  char
AckChars[2]  48 '0'  char
AckChars[3]  48 '0'  char
AckChars[4]  48 '0'  char
AckChars[5]  54 '6'  char
```

So, that seems not to be working.

Comment: Unfortunately for your scenario, the conversion from `"\u06"` to a string with a binary 6 character is done by the compiler at compile-time - at runtime it's just a string with that literal content.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: no problem. I'm not saying "I want to set "\u06" and I demand it to be read as I want.", I am asking "What can I write in the configuration file in order for it to be read as the character, corresponding with that value?

Comment: If you don't find the way how to configure this properly, you can try to parse the codes manually. Given a string with one character point, you can do something like this `byte val = byte.Parse(strWithCode.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);` and then `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(val)`. For multiple characters the similar approach can be used, but you need first to split the string by `\u` or `U+`

Comment: I tried `"AckChars" value = "&#x6;"`. this apparently is encoded as expected, but `XDocument.Parse(xml)` complains with the exception `"hexadecimal value 0x06, is an invalid character"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is due to the code I'm using to read config files. I've added the following (after reading the `value` in `appSettings`):

```
if ((value.ToUpper().StartsWith("\\X")) || 
    (value.ToUpper().StartsWith("\\U")))
{
value = ((char)Int32.Parse(value.Replace(value.Substring(0,2),string.Empty))).ToString();
}
```

Like this, I can put values like `\x03`, `\U0006` or other in my configuration files, and they will be read as single characters, having the integer values as ASCII codes. Further elaboration might be possible (Unicode, e.g.), but this is a first start.

Comment: You don't need to call `Replace`, you just can pass the `value.Substring(2)` to `int.Parse`

Comment: Of course everything depends on what you put into your strings, but if you're using `\U` it's expected that it has a value in the hex format, but you parse it as a decimal value which is wrong or at least confusing. Consider the value for small 'a' in Unicode '\U0061', which is 97 in decimal. But you will convert 61 to char which is '='